# Center all windows title using gconf-editor?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, themes, gtk, gconf

I want to center my windows title like so:

[image: Human]

Instead of having them aligned to the right:

[image: Right]

Is there a setting I can change in `gconf-editor` or is this something controlled by each theme?

Comment: i'm not positive but i think this is part of the (GTK, etc) theme...

Comment: @quack: Thats what I was thinking also, but I figured someone who makes themes might know a setting I could change in the themes `gtkrc` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed part of the theme. It is not configurable through gconf-editor. [**Here**](http://linuxgator.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=1311) is an example of how to edit a theme's XML file.

Before:

```
<draw_ops name="title-text-focused">
   <title color="shade/#000000/0.8" x="0" y="(((height - title_height) / 2)+1)"/>
   <title color="shade/#000000/0.8" x="1" y="(((height - title_height) / 2)+1)"/>
   <title color="shade/#000000/0.8" x="2" y="(((height - title_height) / 2)+1)"/>

   <title color="#f0f0f0" x="0" y="(height - title_height) / 2"/>

</draw_ops>

<draw_ops name="title-text-unfocused">
   <title color="shade/#000000/0.8" x="0" y="(((height - title_height) / 2)+1)"/>
   <title color="shade/#000000/0.8" x="1" y="(((height - title_height) / 2)+1)"/>
   <title color="shade/#000000/0.8" x="2" y="(((height - title_height) / 2)+1)"/>

   <title color="#808080" x="0" y="(height - title_height) / 2"/>

</draw_ops>
```

After:

```
<draw_ops name="title-text-focused">
   <title color="shade/#000000/0.8" x="((3 `max` (width-title_width)) / 2)" y="(((height - title_height) / 2)+1)"/>
   <title color="shade/#000000/0.8" x="((3 `max` (width-title_width)) / 2)" y="(((height - title_height) / 2)+1)"/>
   <title color="shade/#000000/0.8" x="((3 `max` (width-title_width)) / 2)" y="(((height - title_height) / 2)+1)"/>

   <title color="#f0f0f0" x="((3 `max` (width-title_width)) / 2)" y="(height - title_height) / 2"/>

</draw_ops>

<draw_ops name="title-text-unfocused">
   <title color="shade/#000000/0.8" x="((3 `max` (width-title_width)) / 2)" y="(((height - title_height) / 2)+1)"/>
   <title color="shade/#000000/0.8" x="((3 `max` (width-title_width)) / 2)" y="(((height - title_height) / 2)+1)"/>
   <title color="shade/#000000/0.8" x="((3 `max` (width-title_width)) / 2)" y="(((height - title_height) / 2)+1)"/>

   <title color="#808080" x="((3 `max` (width-title_width)) / 2)" y="(height - title_height) / 2"/>

</draw_ops>
```